# Advice on Debugging Machine-Specific Excel VBA Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with dependencies on code in other other Excel workbooks (these dependent .xls's are VB-level references, i.e. via the Tools->References dialog box in the VBA editor), and some dependencies on dll's such as:
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

This sheet has worked for about 2 years on around 20 machines running Windows XP and Office XP. Recently we have taken delivery of 3 new machines (same OS, same office version) which refuse to run this sheet. When the sheet opens, it throws a 'Compile Error', and the session hangs.

If I open the sheet on a 'bad' machine, hold down the left shift key to stop macro's from running, and then go to VBA Editor->Debug->Complie VBAProject, it compiles fine. I am then able to save the sheet and open it normally on a 'bad'  machine. However this new version of the sheet refuses to run on a 'good' machine!!

I think there must be some sort of version mismatch between certain dll's on the 'good' and 'bad' machines. How do I establish what is causing the issue? Are there any tools available for comparing versions of com components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two suggestions

**1)** First open the file with macros disabled. And then check **VBA Editor | Tools | References**. Check for any missing references and then let us know what are they. We will take it from there.

**2)** For references like "**Microsoft Scripting Runtime Object Library**" I never use Early Binding. Early Binding is the major cause for these kind of errors. Just FYI: Early Binding is creating references beforehand via **VBA Editor | Tools | References**. I would recommend changing your code to Late Binding. Here are 2 examples of the same code using "**Microsoft Scripting Runtime Object Library**" with Early Binding and Late Binding

**EARLY BINDING EXAMPLE**

```
'~~> Set Reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime Object Library"

Sub EBExample()
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        '~~> You code
    Next FileItem
End Sub
```

**LATE BINDING EXAMPLE**

```
'~~> This doesn't need a reference
Sub LBExample()
    Dim FSO As Object, SourceFolder As Object, FileItem As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        '~~> You code
    Next FileItem
End Sub
```

As for me I use early binding to take advantage of Intellisense but then convert it to late binding to avoid version-specific code before distributing the code. That ways the code always works. :)

IMP NOTE: Late Binding fails in scenarios where the destination machine doesn't have the relevant dll registered.

**RECOMMENDED LINK**:

**Topic: Using early binding and late binding in Automation**

**Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115

Hope this helps

Sid

Comment: +1 Interesting strategy. It should be noted that it differs from Microsoft's. Quoting from [the link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115): "The advantages given to early binding make it the best choice whenever possible. [...] Early binding is the preferred method. [..] Microsoft recommends early binding in almost all cases." Though maybe not in *this* paticular case.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Thanks :) I believe (and I could be wrong) but MS recommends it based on 2 main reasons. 1) The Intellisense appeal for masses. 2) EB is way much faster than LB. But like I mentioned earlier that I could be wrong. :)

Comment: LB is slow as it goes through dispatch rather than raw interface.

Comment: +1 I typically using late binding especially with automating other Office software but the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime Object Library` is the one I have used early binding with - it improved runtime on my [Dupe Master addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2123-Eliminating-duplicate-data-with-Duplicate-Master-V2.html) by 25-30%

Comment: LB has also been much more effective for me when the powers that be decided to upgrade SOME users to 2010 from 2003.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've checked for missing references and there are none.  I had also considered late binding but it will be a fairly big job to convert! Also, one of the add-ins contains VBA functions that are called direct from cells in the worksheet. Will these work with late binding? Or do I have to do something special?

Comment: @nickos556: It should not be a big job unless you have 1000s and 1000s of code lines :) All you have to do is replace `As Something` to `As Object` and then use `CreateObject("")` to create an instance. Regarding the Add-In, is it at the moment working fine? If it is then changing your code in the above workbook will not have any adverse affect on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to compare references on two different machines is to run a little macro on each pc to show me all the details.

Make sure Excel is set to trust access to the VBA project object model and run the below code on the two versions of your macro.

```
Sub GetReferences()
   Dim r As Object
   For Each r In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
      Debug.Print r.Name, r.Description, r.FullPath
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I ran that code on a good and bad machine and got identical output. I.e. all the references stored within the workbook vba project are identical.

Comment: @nickos556, very strange. If you use late binding like the other person suggested, does the problem go away?